# Can't Change Environment Variables

Tags: python, cmd, execute

I'm trying to set up my command prompt to execute my Python code. I downloaded Python, but it's not showing up in my System Variables. And to add on to that, I don't know how to add System Variables because the buttons are all grayed out:

[image]

Am I doing this wrong or am I totally on the wrong track?

Comment: Use the user-specific buttons. The bottom ones require admin privileges to use.

Comment: If you are working on Windows, there are two sets of environment variables, one of it you can change without admin rights.

Comment: BTW: You write that you *downloaded* python, but not that you **installed** it. Maybe using the installer package will solve your problem out of the box.

Comment: Edit `Path` in the User section, then restart your Command Prompt session

Comment: Maybe [Path Editor](https://patheditor2.codeplex.com/) can help you as it's often difficult to edit such a long string like `PATH`.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: user variables take precedence over system variabnes...

Answer (score 1):

More simple solution, download python again from the website and check to install PATH variables.

Edit: A picture I found on google, since I am using ubuntu.
[image]

Comment: This worked, I just didn't have the box checked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable for python can be set at installation. If you did not set the environment variable at time of installation, please go to PC properties-> Advanced and change the environment variable.

Please note administrative rights are required to perform this action.

I hope this helps.